# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import mysql.connector

my_db = mysql.connector.connect(
    host = "localhost",
    user = "root",
    password = "mypassword",
    database =  "findingimdbscore",
)
my_cursor = my_db.cursor()

my_cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS film_ve_puan (film_name VARCHAR(100),ImbdScore DOUBLE(4),film_id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY)")
```

**All of variables' color changed but film_id did'nt change btw**

Comment: Why am i taking this error idk?Please help

Comment: Change `DOUBLE(4)` to `DOUBLE`.

Comment: @khelwood thanks to you friend,i am so thankful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should change the DOUBLE(4) to only DOUBLE

Answer (score 2):

`DOUBLE(4)` isn't a legal MySQL type.
You could use `FLOAT(4)` or just `DOUBLE`.

```sql
CREATE TABLE film_ve_puan (
  film_name VARCHAR(100),
  ImbdScore DOUBLE,
  film_id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
)
```

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/floating-point-types.html